# typescript access object property: Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, object, properties

I'm working on a codebase where I need to access a value from the `step` property.

```
interface Car {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    color: string;
    step: {
        something: {
            onea: string;
            oneb: string;
        },
        anotherone: {
            twoa: string;
            twob: string;
        }
    }
};

const car: Car = {
    name: 'Some name',
    age: 200,
    color: 'something',
    step: {
        something: {
            onea: 'one a value',
            oneb: 'one b value'
        },
        anotherone: {
            twoa: 'two a value',
            twob: 'two b value',
        }
    }
};

const color = car.color;
const firstStep = car.step[color];
```

`color` will always be an entry in the `step` property and in my example returns an error.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ something: { onea: string; oneb: string; }; anotherone: { twoa: string; twob: string; }; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ something: { onea: string; oneb: string; }; anotherone: { twoa: string; twob: string; }; }'.
```

What I have tried is to use the `typeof` keyword when trying to get the value but again no change.

```
const firstStep = car.step[typeof color]
```

Comment: Will `color` always be one of the keys in `step`?

Comment: Apologies. I've changed the question so it includes all the necessary information.

@RameshReddy, yes it will be one of the keys in `step`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NllErN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yea that's what I'm after. So the bit I was missing was the `as const satisfies Car`. It would be nice to have a basic write-up explaining what this is doing. Thank you.

Comment: Okay I will do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `car` like

```
const car: Car = {
    ⋯✂⋯
    color: 'something',
    ⋯✂⋯
};
```

then you are essentially throwing away any more specific information from the initializer. The compiler will only know that `car` is a `Car`.  That will let you make any changes to `car` consistent with the definition of `Car`, like

```
car.color = "purple";
```

The compiler won't even try to keep track of whatever the actual value of `car.color` is.  It's just `string`:

```
const color = car.color;
//const color: string
```

And so you won't be able to index into `car.step` with `color`, since the compiler will only let you index with the known keys `"something" | "anotherone"`.

```
const firstStep = car.step[color]; // error!
```

---

So if you want `car` to keep track of the specific details from its initialized value, then you can't annotate it.  Furthermore, if you just assign an object literal to it, the compiler won't realize that you want it to pay attention to the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `color` property.  Again, it will just infer `string`, and therefore you can change it:

```
const car = {
    ⋯✂⋯
    color: 'something',
    ⋯✂⋯
};
car.color = "purple";
const color = car.color;
//const color: string
const firstStep = car.step[color]; // error!
```

Oops.

---

You have to go even further, and ask the compiler to treat the initializer value as being as immutable or constant as possible.  You can do this by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on that initializer value:

```
const car = {
    ⋯✂⋯
    color: 'something',
    ⋯✂⋯
} as const;
```

Now the compiler will treat `color` as a [`readonly` property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties) whose type is the string literal `"something"`.  And now, finally, that's enough for the rest of your code to work:

```
const color = car.color;
// const color: "something"
const firstStep = car.step[color]; // okay
```

---

And that's great, except we're not actually using `Car` at all, meaning the compiler won't catch a mistake like

```
const car = {
    ⋯✂⋯
    age: "quite old",
    color: 'something',
    ⋯✂⋯
} as const; // no error
```

where `age` is a `string` instead of a `number`.  To bring back type checking without annotating, we can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const car = {
    ⋯✂⋯
    age: "quite old",
    color: 'something',
    ⋯✂⋯
} as const satisfies Car; // error!
// ----------------> ~~~
// Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
```

The error has been caught, and we can correct it:

```
const car = {
    ⋯✂⋯
    age: 200,
    color: 'something',
    ⋯✂⋯
} as const satisfies Car; // okay
```

So now you have the best of both worlds!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gWAFDKHIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3PkcnA5cQK6kBG0FgSIIA9gBtRUKrXohmrIrQgAHKrmFtC1UeTAALRusVatokBDgy6jIadPmIfa3IWatAXwA0JrXBCiBtCOxu72yGAA7qJWNDbyduFEUaLOca6Jph6+2XgeQvgk5NQqiCgA8vQM2Pi+YiC0yAgYVOiYALw1YURFXADkAMq6KL19Pt2EHFwATAAMs+PhYpLSyH06eobyY75sympdSUrDBkaHR2YWsX2O7MgAbnDi3BA7E0mOaTcWyHwPTy8+rt7N5gaZ-IF9MELKELloUtcUndHs9Xos4clol8kX8UYD0UdcuEiUR8nUMAA6ZZSZCdABEKm4UBU4ggdIK7nqjWpHSalJ5mWQAHohVywE0JFIXIw6uZGjBgFBaANICpaXyoBT9gBtHkAXSEuUKZAgJTKyBVwHE4gAQnAACbnQhijXqjThXpUQbDYgmt7hKZUOYLMESlZejYQU7bAlafawi6R6MMBMY5COa63OD-VH+tPpixfW64gGvUNsUHvNgQoJQEJOjEIr1I7N4tHl+wpbHRX45-EdwgkrI5QXNTU89UMpkstkctguiedMdUyVQQUiher6XyWUNcUKpVgFWqdXLnX6w21PC9M1IZA2qOQTDukRy8Vjt2hz1rIbkX3kPNwU4Kg6QAR24YBIHTcR7TpWN5y3NYky2BhALjVVUySZCzhfNMMy9LM+3bKt7E+AifhLXMB2QSs4RrKE6xhBs4SbNYWyItCWKxZse0o-sSMHUMhxo9hqAlPdRzfMMaSXflV3XIVxO5RC6Ww+Q6V3eVFWVVVT0pc9VwNYVFNEABrOAAE98CNa8TVvFAADFgAADwgR1cKU98ME-d5v29P9RngohA2QMCIKgiRYKC51EPWE4UM4pQMOY+w1JTFKjnwtZCLbRLMsLciUD4ssBJo6K-ACWt6w8riYh40RkVLPKki7ere1y8qKyEnJRM8mg4DAYBqAVU00AwOdXz3aTeWXAVfBFPqeRAtKNM5KSDx0k9ZM1AyVgNayrxvUo7yckhxAbBdvM6GqehNL1fxGP1ypC4NyqWpD4sYZr4wyuNPvkTC4Sy74UFbJrOtIgrsoojjqNoi56OhLgbqOVi+nYjrqLYVq2N4jiIcE95hI8XqXWoAahpGsS2kkqbFw1FcVgUxaVJWzT920o9dO2rVVV1QzLzwfAgA)